# How can I compile a more complex C project without a makefile

Tags: cryptography

I downloaded this program:
[enter link description here](https://github.com/assaabloy-ppi/salt-channel-c)
According to the instructions, I could not translate it. So I decided to compile it myself, the files that are in the exampes folder. I tried to write a Makefile for compiling source files, but I was a beginner in the makefile and it gives me a lot of errors. I'm still learning how to write Makefile files, so I thought I'd try to manually create object files and compile them together. But he gives me this error, which you can see in picture1. I added these three functions to the code so that they are globally static and I managed to connect the linkers, but when I tried to compile it, it listed these errors in Picture2. Didn't I know how to move on, can't anyone advise me please?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRA1O.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NNr3.jpg)

I added a reference for the pthread library and that -l pthread so I avoided a few errors but there are more

Comment: This library is very complex. You should use `cmake` to create a Makefile for it as indicated, and then use that Makefile. There's no simple way to tell you how to compile this. If there were, it wouldn't be configured with something as complex as `cmake`. https://cmake.org

Comment: I did it as you type, I ran cmake, it created a makefile for me, I compiled it but nowhere in the folder did I see executable applications, so I decided to solve it like this.

Comment: Look under the `build/` directory. The executables and libraries are all in there. If you run `git status --ignored` it'll show you every file or directory that got created by the build.

Comment: Yes, I look in the / build directory and see the static salt.a library, but not the executable files. Can you advise me who they are?    With the help of your display, I see all object files, but I don't see them in the folder, how do I get to them or how do I manipulate them now?

Comment: Run `ccmake` (two "c"). It will let you configure the build and enable building the examples.

Comment: You were right now. Thank you very much. Why were such compilation examples not allowed then?

Comment: In normal usage, you don't want to build the examples. You just want the library to include it in some other project.